# Windows 10 ethernet public private flip flopping

Tags: networking, windows-10, router

I am in the processing of building a new Win 10 computer.  I have two harddrives in my box, one with win 10 the other xp.  The xp has run for a long time with no problems.

The latest Win 10 version 1703 Creators was installed two days ago.  From the outset it has had issues.  The ethernet constantly goes on and off line with a red x on the icon.  When viewing the networks through the System panel, it switches between public and private networks constantly, every 10 seconds or so.  The private networks window shows many subnetworks.

It goes up and down so fast that I can't access or test much with the network.  The troubleshooter just says cable not connected which is not true.  I have not been able to force it to go all private.  Accessing the registry key for the profile shows it set to private (1) network.  Ipconfig command shows exactly what I expect to see in the ethernet device config.

The network configuration is exactly the same as my xp and my win 7 laptop which both work fine and are rock solid.

I have a DSL router/modem that is set as the gateway and runs DHCP for the rest of the family.  I have dedicated IPs and DNS selections for my own computers. Everything runs on the 192.168.x.x subnet.

Using the laptop I downloaded the latest cumulative updates for the OS from microsquish and installed them NP.  The ethernet devices is locked in that I can't delete it and create it myself.  Only by removing the device and then scanning for it can I get it set up.

I have tried full DHCP and specific settings, many suggestions on the internet(mostly about WIFI which I am not using).  The built-in NIC is Intel 8257V and I have installed the latest and greatest driver.  I have tried a clean boot and turned off many services.  It only tends to disable it entirely or turn it on with no changes.

Suggestions, links, hints welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a bad network driver or faulty hardware. Start by trying different versions of network drivers. And a new network cable.

Comment: When I boot the XP os from the same box the network is fine, so I am pretty sure the hardware and cable are ok.  When I remove the network driver and go with the generic driver Windows provides I get the same issue.  I think the last driver is two years old, but I will give it a look..

Comment: I agree the fact XP has no issues strongly suggests the hardware is OK. That leaves drivers, and to a much less likely degree, the the particular configuration of the network.